# The joint density function of the minimum and maximum of two independent uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

Let $X,Y$ be two independent $Unif([0,1])$ random variables, denote $U=\min(X,Y)$, and $V=\max(X,Y)$. Find the joint density function of $U$ and $V$.

I'm trying to find the joint density function with 
$f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{X,Y}(u,v)+f_{X,Y}(v,u)$ for $0<u<v<1$. But I don't know how to proceed from there. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have (removing the negligible events) for all non-negative measurable function $f$,
$$
E(f(U,V))=E(f(X,Y)1_{X<Y})+E(f(Y,X)1_{Y<X})=2\int_{[0,1]^2} f(x,y)\,1_{x<y}\,dxdy
$$
Hence the joint density function is $f_{U,V}(u,v)=21_{u<v}$.